# Idioms: Should it be " the internet is a seemingly infinite well of information" or "the internet is a seemingly infinite wealth of information"

Tags: idioms

The title says it all. I have heard the phrase used either way, but "well" makes more sense to me. My editor and I are both at a stalemate with this one.

Comment: Either will do. Why not toss a coin?

Comment: An infinite well is usually said to be "bottomless", and a "well" is not usually used in that context.

Comment: I'd argue that both 'well' and 'wealth' are used in a quasi-quantifier way here (cf 'a lot of common sense', 'wealth of ...' being a snowclone, and that perhaps for this reason 'a seemingly infinite' doesn't sit too well with either expression. 'A seemingly infinite wealth of' sounds unnatural to my ears, and a seemingly infinite well is perhaps over-stretching the mental picture. I'd use 'a seemingly infinite source'.

Comment: ... As @Jason points out, 'well' has at least connotations of 'good' (a **good** source) and 'wealth' must _denote_ 'good'. “The internet is a seemingly infinite source of invaluable information” works but loses punchiness.

Comment: That said, *the Internet* is a proper noun, despite widespread misusage. (**An** internet is also a thing, but nearly everyone means the one specific Internet.)

Comment: @WeatherVane An infinite well could also mean a well that never runs out of water (by some magical means, perhaps). It works just as well as "wealth of information", and "infinite well of ____" makes _more_ sense than "infinite wealth of ____" to me.

Comment: I would say that "infinite wealth" sounds positive, but "bottomless well" is a bit more negative. Maybe "youtube is a bottomless well of cat videos" vs. "wikipedia has an infinite wealth of knowledge available"

Comment: Perhaps it is rather an infinite sink of information ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Wealth of information" is a (somewhat) [commonly used idiom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wealth%20of%20information%2C%20well%20of%20information&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwealth%20of%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20of%20information%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwealth%20of%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwell%20of%20information%3B%2Cc0), as compared to "Well of information".

As per the Cambridge dictionary, one of the meanings of [wealth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wealth) (in Business English) is given as:

> **a large amount of something good:**
>
> ***a wealth of data/detail/information*** The website gives a wealth of data
>   on a company's stock.
>
> *He brings a wealth of industry experience to his
>   new position.*

Comment: But doesn't this make 'a seemingly infinite wealth of ...' an overegging? Wouldn't 'a seemingly infinite source of ...' be preferable?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, because information can also be bad. By specifying *wealth*, it's focusing only on the good information. The equivalent of *infinite **wealth** of information* would be *infinite well of **good** information*. At least as far as the cited definition implies . . .

Comment: @Jason Bassford Agreed; the 'good' needs specifying to remain felicitous; but the overegging still applies. // This puts 'wealth' (or the lexeme 'a wealth of', at least) alongside 'galore' (corresponds to 'many gay/resplendent'), in my opinion, in a class where a word (hmm ... or lexeme!?) must be classed as both a quantifier and an adjective at the same time. Muchgood / manygay.

Comment: Good answer, but it's worth noting that there's nothing _wrong_ with using "well of information". It makes perfect sense. If you like how it sounds, use it.

Comment: This isn't really an idiom. The meaning, for both forms, is transparent from its constituent words.

Comment: I don't like this answer as it is now, because it does not address the usage in the sentence with the verb "is". "*The internet is a [...] wealth of information*" does **not** sound idiomatic.

Answer (score 10):

I think 'wealth' is the most appropriate choice, for the reasons already given, but I question the use of 'is' as the verb - "is ... a wealth" doesn't sound right. It would be better to say 'provides us with' or 'affords us'. Maybe you should consider changing the verb or finding another word altogether, such as 'fount', 'source', or 'wellspring'.

Comment: I agree, or simply 'has' a wealth of information